# How to display different data on Morris Chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I have a morris chart loaded with a collection of data.  In each item there are 6 different data values.  I want to toggle between 2 different sets of data.

As a simple example here is my data of which I want to always display the target and toggle between A/B and A2/B2:

```
[
{
'Target_A':'0',
'Target_B':'0',
'A':'12',
'B':'12',
'A2':'12',
'B2':'4',
'xKeyVal':'2011-12-19'
},
{
'Target_A':'0',
'Target_B':'0',
'A':'12',
'B':'12',
'A2':'8',
'B2':'3',
'xKeyVal':'2012-03-12'
}
]
```

Here is my code to toggle, however it does not work.  I can load either set of data just fine on the page load, but I cannot change it successfully yet.

```
function ToggleCC(isChecked){ //This is fired from a checkbox
if(isChecked)
{
    chart.options.ykeys = ['A2', 'Target_A', 'B2', 'LastTarget_B'];
    chart.options.lables= ['A2', 'Target_A', 'B2', 'LastTarget_B'];
}
else
{
    chart.options.ykeys = ['A', 'Target_A', 'B', 'Target_B'];
    chart.options.labels = ['A', 'Target_A', 'B', 'Target_B'];
}
//chart.setData();
chart.redraw();
```

}

chart is a global variable created in the document.ready function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    chart = new Morris.Line({
         ...
```

How can I update my keys and labels and 'update' my chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to rebind my existing data I tried passing in the chart data object to the setData method like so:

```
chart.setData(chart.data);
```

However, the chart.Data object does not match the format of the data I entered the first time.  My solution was to set my json data in a variable and then call setData and pass in that data.  This is the final code.

```
var dataGraph = 'The exact same string/data which was in the Line Chart constructor option.';


   $( document ).ready(function() {
        chart = new Morris.Line({
            // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
            element: 'IOPChart',
            // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
            // the chart.
            data: dataGraph ,
... continue options...
```

Finally in my update function I just setData to that variable from the pageload.

```
chart.setData(dataGraph);
```